# SelectOneMenu + CommmandButton

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

Hi I have the follonwing selectOneMenu

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{modelsController.selected.idBrands}">
    <f:selectItems value="{brandsController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" />
</h:selectOneMenu> <br/>
```

which is populated with all available brands in the bean.

And I would like to create a button that retrives the brand selected in the mentioned selectOneMenu and display the records in the bean filtered by the selection (what I mean, is that if the user selected, aBrand in the selectOneMenu all models from abrand will be shown in a datatable.

This is a simple CRUD jsf 2.0 with EcpliseLink.

Could somebody point me in the right direction?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<h:form>` and a `<h:commandButton>`:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{modelsController.selected.idBrands}">  
        <f:selectItems value="{brandsController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" />  
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <br />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{modelsController.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

And define an action method which fills the datatable list based on the selected item.

```
public String submit() {
    items = itemDAO.load(selected.getIdBrands());
}
```

And display it in the `<h:dataTable>` the usual way.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{modelsController.items}" ... >
```

Comment: Thanks,
are you using Hibernates itemDAO? Cause I can not reech .load from anywhere

Comment: No, it's just a simple self-explaining abstraction of a DAO class. Do whatever DAO thing you want as long as it returns the desired `List<Items>`.

Comment: OK I thin'k i've got it 
public List<Models> findByBrands(Brands id_brand){
        CriteriaQuery cq = (CriteriaQuery) em.createNamedQuery("SELECT m FROM Models WHERE m.id_brand :id_brand);
        cq.select(cq.from(Modelos.class));
        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
In nede to get the argument in the sql query, is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is. If you can't figure it in the JPA docs/tutorials, ask a new question. This is off topic.